# What is the way to make an internal API

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, api-design, services, symfony

I have a Symfony project.

I want to make this project API based, but also with a Web UI.

So, I have 2 Bundles, `ApplicationBundle` and `WebUiBundle`.

In Application Bundle, I have `application`, `domain` and `infrastructure` (tiers?), where `application` has the public API (presentation layer).

Now, I need to access an API from the `WebUiBundle`, but not the public API for first-rendering, I want to make it internal.

What is the best approach for this?

Since I will have `application`, `domain` and `infrastructure` services, I thought about making an `application service` for each `domain service` I need.
For example, `Users` service needs an interface and validations (domain), an implementation (infrastructure) and I then the Users Application Service, which would be nothing more than an API that is exposed internally. So the WebUiBundle only interacts with Application API.

What do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by "*internal*"? A private API?

Comment: @Laiv I mean to have a WebUI that needs to reference the Application Services internally. (Not making REST calls for example). The WebUI bundle would have to be deployed with the backend Application. I guess that way there isn't  any way to really decouple the WebUI but to make http request to localhost...

Comment: If I understood well. You want a public API (Rest) and a frontend. The frontend is going to be rendered at server side and it doesn't consume the public API (REST). Am I right?

Comment: @Laiv yes that is. I don't want to use the public API for first render (because it is faster in server side) and then use the API with AJAX. But I still want to somehow make an internal API so that the REST uses the same API as the WebUI, so I don't have to duplicate code for example for getting all the users, or getting users that meet certain criteria. That is why I thought about an Application Service that is consumed by both the App Presentation Layer REST and the Presentation Layer Web UI.

Answer (score 1):

*Whatever you do keep the Domain layer pure, without any dependencies to other layers.*

> In Application Bundle, I have application, domain and infrastructure (tiers?), where application has the public API (presentation layer).

**The Application layer is not the Presentation layer**.

The `Application layer` exposes the use cases of your domain. It's a thin layer, with no business rules. In general there is only one layer of this type. In this layer you most probable have Application services (classes) that basically do this: load an `Aggregate` root from the `Repository`, calls a method on it and then it persists the changes to the `Repository`. Of course, it may have other responsibilities like authorization: for example here you check that if the user is an `admin` it can delete any `Product`.

The `Presentation layer` is the client of the `Application layer`. There could be more than one `Presentation layer` that uses the `Application layer`. The main responsibility of this layer is to gather the input from the user and call `Application services` - services that live in the `Application layer`. One other responsibility is to display the data to the user. Examples of `Presentation layers`: A MVC presentation layer, a REST endpoint.

> Since I will have application, domain and infrastructure services, I thought about making an application service for each domain service I need

You should create an application service for each use case, not for every domain service. One note about domain services: be aware of the [anemic domain model](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).

About the types of use of the Application layer: if you host the `Presentation layer` and the `Application layer` on the same server, for example if you have a `MCV` on top of the `Application layer`, then you can call the `Application services` directly from your `Controller`, like normal method calls. If you separate the frontend from the backend then you cannot call the application services directly but you can use a `REST` endpoint on top of the `Application layer`.

> Now, I need to access an API from the WebUiBundle, but not the public API for first-rendering, I want to make it internal.

`Application layer` is always internal. It needs a `Presentation layer` to make it accessible.